# How to count the number of comment and flag in a node?

Tags: 8, theming, nodes, comments, flags

I want to display on my node the number of comment and flag.

What should I add to my TWIG to get this?

How to count the number of comment and flag in a node?

Here is an example :

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the comment count you can get it in the node twig by:

```
{{ content.comment['#items'].comment_count }}
```

But the flag count i think there is no way to get it directly in the twig:
There is extension called `flagcount` in the flag module but it requires the flag object which is not available in node twig.
From comment section of `flagcount` callback function in ***flag/src/TwigExtension/FlagCount.php***

> ```
> /**
>    * Gets the number of flaggings for the given flag and flaggable.
>    *
>    * @param \Drupal\flag\FlagInterface $flag
>    *   The flag entity.
>    * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $flaggable
>    *   The flaggable entity.
>    *
>    * @return string
>    *   The number of times the flaggings for the given parameters.
>    */
> ```

So the only way is to pass by preprocess like the following:

```
/**
 * Implements hook__preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function YOURMODULE_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['elements']['#node'];
  // Set your flag id here.
  $flag_id = 'bookmark';
  $variables['flag_count'] = \Drupal::service('flag.count')->getEntityFlagCounts($node)[$flag_id];
}
```

And then in you twig you can do:

```
{{ flag_count }}
```

Comment: Not sure, but you probably have to care about caching for the flag. Otherwise it won't increment unless you clear the cache. Maybe add the flag as #markup or #inline_template and let if have cache tagged with the nid and the flag id?

Comment: I managed to get the number of comments for a node with this code `{{ node.field_article_commentaire.comment_count }}` but it does not work with products. I tested this code and it returns nothing `{{ product.field_produit_avis.comment_count }}`

Comment: Did you check that the comment field in product is `field_produit_avis` ?

Comment: @berramou Yes it is the machine name of the field `field_produit_avis`